# How to update react context in child elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hi i have problem with context in react. I need to update context data after i fetch some data in child component:

Here is my app code

```
export default class App extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { loggedInUser: null };
        this.onLogin = this.onLogin.bind(this);
        this.onLogout = this.onLogout.bind(this);

    }

    onLogin(value) {
        this.setState({ loggedInUser: value });
    }

    onLogout(value) {
        this.setState({ loggedInUser: null });
    }

    render() {

        let content = null;

        if (this.state.loggedInUser == null) {
            content = <div> <LoginScreen onLogin={this.onLogin}  /> </div>
        }
        else {
            content = <div> <Application onLogout={this.onLogout} /> </div>
        }

        return (

            <MuiThemeProvider theme={ApplicationTheme}>
                <Context.Provider value={{
                    user:this.state.loggedInUser,
                    updateUser: (user) =>{this.user=user},
                    company: null,
                    updateCompany:(company) => {this.company=company},
                    role: null,
                    updateRole:(role) => {this.role = role},
                }}>
                    {content}
                </Context.Provider>
            </MuiThemeProvider>

        );
    }
```

From this component i go to login screen and AFTER that in component where i should select role. In this component i need update role data in context. How to do this please?

```
export class RoleSelector extends Component {
    static displayName = RoleSelector.name;
    static contextType = Context;



    render() {
        console.log(this.context);
        this.context.updateCompany(1);
        console.log(this.context);
        console.log("Afterext)");
        let companies = this.context.userCompanies.map(u =>
            <Grid item lg={6} xs={12} key={u.company.id}>
                <UserCompany userCompany={u}> </UserCompany>
            </Grid>
        );

        return (
                    <Container className="roleSelector">
                        <Context.Consumer>
                            <Grid container direction="column" justify="center" alignItems="center" alignContent="center"
                                  spacing={1}>
                                <Box my={2}>
                                    <Typography variant="h1" align="center">Vyberte typ uživateľa</Typography>
                                </Box>
                                <Grid container className="company" justify={"center"}>
                                    {companies}
                                </Grid>
                            </Grid>
                        </Context.Consumer>
                    </Container>
        );
    }


}
```

I tried to pass method to update data in context but it return unchanged context. (Data has same values after using updateCompany in my example)

Thx for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have `const Context = React.createContext()`, I'll do something like this:

1. will add `company` and `role` to `App` state
2. will add methods for updating `company` and `role` and bind them in `App` constructor.
3. pass all 4 items to `Context.Provider` value. It would look like something like this:

```
value={{
 user: this.state.loggedInUser,
 updateUser: this.updateUser,
 company: this.state.company,
 updateCompany: this.updateCompany,
 role: this.state.role,
 updateRole: this.updateRole,
}}
```

4. in the `RoleSelector` component, you'll have something like this:

```
<Context.Consumer>
  {({user, updateUser, company, updateCompany, role, updateRole}) => (...your jsx)}
</Context.Consumer>
```

Comment: thx.I will try this.  I hope there will be better solution if i would save more variables in context not just few.

Comment: Okay. Let me know if this solution worked for you. I might have other thing to suggest as well

Comment: Yes this works.However when i change data on click on link element data will reset after route changed

Comment: My fault. it works as I wish. Just one last thing. Is there chance that context stay unchanged after refresh page?

Comment: Nope. If you want to persist data than use `localStorage` and than when `App` component mounts update state from local storage. Also afterwards, keep in mind that on each state update you will have to update localStorage so the state and LS are always in sync. But than, you might have to think about sessions and how to handle when session expire and you have logged user in storage and state. Hope I didn't go to far with this assumptions about sessions. Maybe using `sessionStorage` will do better job in that case

Comment: I think that local storage could be useful in this case. Anyway thx for your help.